# Phase/argument of this function

Tags: complex-numbers

I have:
$Y(e^{j\omega})=-2+4e^{-j\omega}-2e^{-2j\omega}$. What is the the phase, $\angle Y(e^{j\omega})$, if it is evaluated at $\omega=\pi$?

Comment: What is the complex number you get when you plug in $\omega = \pi$? What is its phase?

Comment: @Matti P I get -2-4-2=-8. It would be tan^{-1}(0/-8). If I solve the equation directly, I get $-\omega$. Then, I plug the $\omega=\pi$

Comment: Yeah so you put the point $(-8,0)$ to the complex plane; what is its phase, judging by the picture?

Comment: I would get $\pi$. Is it possible the answer is $-\pi$, $-3\pi$, or $3\pi$?

Comment: Yes, it's possible since the period is $2\pi$. So any multiple of $2\pi$ can be added.

Comment: I plot the phase of this function using matlab and I get a periodical function from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. The max value is $\pi$ and the min value is $-\pi$

Comment: I think it's not possible that the result is other than $-\pi$ if the input is $\omega=\pi$. What are my mistakes on this?